# Obtaining invalid rows of dataset

Tags: python, pandas

BY a given dataframe:

```
  Account ID Account Name First Name   Created On  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9
0      12345      lexcorp        Lex  2011-01-12          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1     918299       oscorp     Norman  2014-04-29          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2      88888       dococt       Otto   2013-08-08         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3        NaN       asdasd        NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4        asd          NaN        NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
5        NaN          NaN        NaN       asdasd         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
6        NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

The goal is to write a function that cleans up that dataframe and detects which rows are the invalid ones.

Currently i already removed invalid (all NaN) rows and ignored them for the invalids, and detected rows with NaN account ids and detected them as invalid:

```
def clean(df):
    # Cleaning empty rows/columns to minify filesizes
    df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
    df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)

    # Cleaning rows that does not have an account_id
    clean_df = df[df[CsvFields.ACCOUNT_ID].notna()]

    # Removing non-integer account_ids
    clean_df[CsvFields.ACCOUNT_ID] = pandas.to_numeric(clean_df[CsvFields.ACCOUNT_ID], errors='coerce')
    clean_df = clean_df.dropna(subset=[CsvFields.ACCOUNT_ID])

    # Obtaining the invalid rows
    invalids = []
    if len(df) != len(clean_df):
        invalids = df.merge(clean_df, on=CsvFields.ACCOUNT_ID, how='outer', indicator=True)
        invalids = invalids.loc[invalids._merge == 'left_only', invalids.columns != '_merge']
    return clean_df, invalids
```

When doing the merge, in case i have rows where my account id is not a number, the merge will fail due to the index field not being a number.

How can i detect those cases and add that to the invalids dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to coerce the non numeric values to NA and dropping the rows where there are NA's in the Account ID column? I think the following should allow you to merge the other valid rows correctly. You could probably also add the invalid rows to a new dataframe by reassigning.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df[['Account ID']].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```